# stange behaviour UIRefreshControl with UISearchBar

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uirefreshcontrol

i'm using UIRefreshControl with UISearchBar when i'm pull to refresh i see a white background at the top of uiviewcontroller

```
   UISearchBar *searchBar =
[[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:
 CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 44.0)];
searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;

 _refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[_refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(update) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.tableView addSubview:_refreshControl];
```

[image]

[image]

the problem is the white background above

any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Create a background view for the table and set its color to clearColor, like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.tableView.backgroundView = [UIView new];
    self.tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Comment: thanks crazy hack but any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I think it's just normal behavior for a tableView -- the default background color is white and that's what it uses to paint the top and bottom areas outside the cells.  I don't know why just clearing the .backgroundColor property on the tableView doesn't work though, I've always had to assign a view as the background instead.

Comment: This worked for me too.  This answer should be marked as correct.